# Reading JSON files in a child process

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have two node apps that are related together. One of them is called from another using a child process `exec` method. In the noted app, I am reading some JSON files with this method:

```
function readAsync(files, configs, callBack) {
var result = [];
files.forEach(function (item, i) {
    result = result.concat(JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(item, { encoding: 'utf8' })));
    if (i === files.length - 1 && typeof (callBack) === 'function') {
        var _ret = _.chain(result)
            .uniqBy(function (x) { return x.url })
            .sortBy(function (x) { return x.title })
            .value();
        filterByConfigs(_ret, configs, function (filteredResult) {
            callBack(filteredResult);
        });
    }
})}
```

I get this error in reading and parsing JSON files. However, there isn't any error and problem when I run the child app independently.

```
undefined:1

SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at Object.parse (native)
    at E:\Open Source Projects\src\cli\readFiles.js:30:37
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at readAsync (E:\Open Source Projects\src\cli\readFiles.js:29:11)
    at E:\Open Source Projects\src\cli\readFiles.js:19:9
    at E:\Open Source Projects\src\cli\getJsonFiles.js:18:13
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
```

JSON files sample:

```
[
  {
    "title": "Document Manager",
    "subTitle": "Document manager - indexing, Filter file and rename - delete - share document.",
    "url": "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.document.manager.filescanner&hl=en&gl=us",
    "appId": "com.document.manager.filescanner",
    "price": "0",
    "minInstalls": 1000000,
    "score": 4.2,
    "version": "1.4"
  },
  {
    "title": "Mini Scanner - PDF Scanner App",
    "subTitle": "Fast easy way to scanner, professional pdf documents, Support SD card + Send Fax",
    "url": "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.simplescan.miniscanner&hl=en&gl=us",
    "appId": "com.simplescan.miniscanner",
    "price": "0",
    "minInstalls": 100000,
    "score": 4.6,
    "version": "1.0.9"
  }
]
```

Has anyone gotten stuck in this situation yet? Thanks.

Comment: can you add to your question the json file content?

Comment: @CiroSpaciari sure. it's there now.

Comment: Try calling `toString()` after reading.

Comment: Are you sure your JSON has been fully written out when you attempt to read it? In other words, isn’t it written asynchronously and not fully written before you start your child process (or signal it to read the file)?

Comment: @CiroSpaciari Your second hipotesis and @jcaron comment are totally right! I've used an async `writeFile` method in the first app to write the json files. Making it sync (writeFileSync) fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I run the code bellow trying to simulate te problem and i get when a file have a incomplete or broken json. Can you verify what you got in `console.log` when trying log the read/parse errors?

```
var fs = require("fs");
function readAsync(files, configs, callBack) {
    var result = [];
    files.forEach(function (item, i) {

      console.log("reading file:", item);
      try{
          result = result.concat(JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(item, { encoding: 'utf8' })));
      }catch(ex){
          console.log("bad file :c :", item, ex);
      }
      if (i === files.length - 1 && typeof (callBack) === 'function'){
            callBack(result);
      }
  });
}

readAsync([ "test.json" ], null, function(obj){
  console.log(obj);
});
```